# Where can I find the xml data file generated in XML Publisher of Oracle EBS R12?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs, oracle-xml-publisher

I am looking for the oracle table name that stores the xml data file that gets generated after we run the xml publisher report.

Comment: Are you looking for the Data Definition File which is being stored table name or generated XML output?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the XML data which are generated upon executing BI Publisher, it is not stored in the database tables, however, these files can be accessed from the server. The location is

```
$APPLOUT/{REPORTNAME}_{REQUEST_ID}_{COUNT}.<filetype>
```

- REPORTNAME -  is the concurrent program short name
- REQUEST_ID - is the concurrent request ID
- COUNT - is a counter based on the number of times a request has been re-published.

Alternatively, the generated XML can be retrieved from the Concurrent Program form as well, see the enclosed screenshot for reference.
[image: Generated XML]

Data Definition and Templates are in fact stored in the database table, the table name is

```
XDO_LOBS
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is not stored in a table, it's held on the server (in the same directory that normally stores the output from concurrent programs).

If you want to view the XML :

Query back your concurrent request, click on the 'Diagnostics' button.  For a BI Publisher executable the 'View XML' button will be enabled

Comment: This is mostly always true, but not always true.  There are cases where the XML is stored in a table as CLOB.  For example in AR module, payment instructions XML is stored in ```IBY_TRXN_DOCUMENTS.DOCUMENT```, which you might need if you want to customize the format payment instruction report.